# How can I use a constexpr function during pack expansion?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I want to do the following:

```
// have a constexpr function
template<class T>
constexpr T square( T const i )
{
    return i * i;
}

// transform a std::integer_sequence<> by calling the constexpr function on every integer
template<class Fn, class T, T... values>
static constexpr auto make_type( Fn fn, std::integer_sequence<T, values...> )
{
    return std::integer_sequence<T, fn( values )...>{};
}

// so that I can use it like so
using type = decltype( make_type( square, std::integer_sequence<int, 1, 2, 3>{} ) );
```

However, I get the following error:

> ...\main.cpp|19|error: 'fn' is not a constant expression|

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fn` is not usable in a constant expression - it's a bog-standard block-scope variable. You have to pass the functor as a type.

```
template <typename Fn, typename T, T... values>
static constexpr std::integer_sequence<T, Fn{}(values)...>
make_type(std::integer_sequence<T, values...>) {return {};}
```

And rewrite your function as

```
struct Square {
    template <typename T> constexpr T operator()(T const& t)
    {return t*t;}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact that `constexpr` is not part of the type of a function pointer, `square` is a template, so you can't form a pointer to it by the usual implicit decay.

But it is not necessary to alter the signature of your `make_type` function to make this work. Rewrite `Square` as a functor:

```
struct Square {
    template<class T>
    constexpr T operator()( T const& i )
    {
        return i * i;
    }
};
```

And call it like this:

```
using type = decltype( make_type( square{}, std::integer_sequence<int, 1, 2, 3>{} ) );
```

In C++17 you will be able to use a `constexpr` lambda:

```
constexpr auto square = [](auto const& i) { return i * i; };

using type = decltype( make_type( square, std::integer_sequence<int, 1, 2, 3>{} ) );
```